# UI sortable Store and Restore with multiple connect list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a connected sortable list of three. I stored the order in database(MySQL) but I couldn't restore..

```
<div class="sortable1">
<div id="widget1"></div>
<div id="widget2"></div>
<div id="widget3"></div>
</div>

<div class="sortable2">
<div id="widget4"></div>
<div id="widget5"></div>
<div id="widget6"></div>
</div>

<div class="sortable3">
<div id="widget7"></div>
<div id="widget8"></div>
<div id="widget9"></div>
</div>
```

But i have an array previous sortable result like

```
var savedOrder = [["widget5","widget2","widget3","widget1"],["widget4","widget10","widget7"],["widget8","widget9","widget6"]];
```

how can restore using above array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why not re-arrange in accordance to the database value when you display it on page. I cannot help you on this one, you need to figure it out on your own.

But, If it comes to using JavaScript/jQuery , then use following on document load

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     //......Code goes here
});
```

or create event of sortable i.e;

```
$(".sortable").sortable(function(){
   create : function(){
           //.......Code goes here
     }
  })
```

And add following block to respective blocks(or any of the sortable initalization),

```
    var oldList, newList, item;
    var savedOrder = [
        ["widget5", "widget2", "widget3", "widget1"],
        ["widget4", "widget10", "widget7"],
        ["widget8", "widget9", "widget6"]
    ];
    var sortableSelector;
    $(savedOrder).each(function (key, value) {
        if (key == 0) {
            sortableSelector = ".sortable1";
        } else if (key == 1) {
            sortableSelector = ".sortable2";
        } else {
            sortableSelector = ".sortable3";
        }
        $(value).each(function (i, data) {
            //Detach element from the Document 
            var element = $("." + data).detach();
            //Append it to respective sortable 
            $(sortableSelector).append(element);
        });
    });
```

What is done?

- First iterate though the loop of sort order
- Pick sortable items and detach it from DOM. Then, append to
  respective sortable

#### Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39ZvN/935/)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you @Runcorn. You done a great job for me.. Thanks a lot:)